# Is R an interpreted or compiled programming language?

Tags: r, interpreted-language, compiled-language

Is R an interpreted or compiled programming language?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-is-R_003f) says: "The core of R is an interpreted computer language".

Answer (score 11):

It's more accurate to say that the *default implementation* of some language is interpreted or compiled. But not the language itself!

Answer (score 10):

You can build a compiler or interpreter for any programming language. In general, the language itself is not compiled or interpreted.

So, R could be either interpreted or compiled. Nonetheless, in the most common implementation, R is interpreted.

Answer (score 9):

R is an [interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language).

Answer (score 3):

R doesn't compile. There are projects that try to get it compiled: http://www.hipersoft.rice.edu/rcc/ , http://www.rforge.net/r2c/ but I can't find any currently supported.

That said, the performance on modern hardware seems reasonable for even larger workloads I have thrown at it (millions of records).

Comment: Those aren't ready yet.  See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452235/deploying-r-without-r-into-c-or-c

Comment: The folks at Revolution Computing (http://www.revolution-computing.com/) are working on a version of R that's supposedly a few times faster than the standard distribution.  It's still interpreted, though.

Comment: John, REvo R is still essentially the same R but it ships with MKL (faster blas) and (somewhat) easier parallel usage. The engine is identical for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score -2):

R is definitely written in C.  I asked myself this question alittle while ago, and resolved it by downloaded the source code from http://www.r-project.org/.