# How to generate and draw Mandelbrot sets with parallel code in R?

Tags: r, cluster-computing, mandelbrot

I would like to do parallel coding in R. So far I have found some examples like the following, which works fine:

```
library(parallelly)
library(parallel)
library(future)

# define function to test whether an number is prime
is_prime <- function(num)
{
  if(num == 2 | num == 3)
    return(TRUE)
  if(num == 1)
    return(FALSE)
  if(num %% 2 == 0)
    return(FALSE)
  root <- floor(sqrt(num))
  for(elt in seq(5,root))
  {
    if (num %% elt == 0)
      return(FALSE)
  }
  return(TRUE)
}

# get random sample of 1 million integers from integers between 1 and
# 10 million
# set seed so the random sample will be the same every time
set.seed(2)
sample_numbers <- sample(10000000, 1000000)


start <- proc.time()
cl <- makeCluster(4) 
results <- parSapply(cl , sample_numbers , is_prime)
stopCluster(cl)
end <- proc.time()
print(end - start)
```

Now I would like to build a script to run in parallel the function that generates mandelbrot sets. In the following script, two Mandelbrot sets are generated and plotted, sequentially. I want to convert that process to parallel processing, in which both xlim, ylim and colors can be passed to the function, but I don't know how to do that. Below is the code that is intended to be parallel.

```
library(mandelbrot)
xlim <- c(-0.8438146, -0.8226294)
ylim <- c(0.1963144, 0.2174996)

view <- mandelbrot(xlim, ylim,iterations = 1000, resolution = 1000)
cols <- mandelbrot_palette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"), fold = FALSE) 

plot(view, col = cols)


xlim <- c(-2, 2)
ylim <- c(-2, 2)
view <- mandelbrot(xlim, ylim, resolution = 1000, iterations = 1000)

blues <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9, "Blues")
cols <- mandelbrot_palette(blues, in_set = "white",
                           fold = TRUE, reps = 2)
plot(view, col = cols, transform = "log")
```

[set 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOD31.png)
[set 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRdkT.png)

I would be very grateful if someone could help me to correctly build the following script, which allows generating and graphing mandelbrot sets in parallel.

```
library(parallelly)
library(parallel)
library(future)
library(mandelbrot)


#The following is the function that allows you to call the mandelbrot set generator
get_mandelbrot_set <-function(xlim,ylim,color) {
  
  view <- mandelbrot(xlim, ylim,iterations = 1000, resolution = 1000)
  cols <- mandelbrot_palette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, color), fold = FALSE) 
  
  plot(view, col = cols) #I don't know if it can be graphed here, inside the function that is executed in parallel or has to be executed at the end, but I don't know how?
}

repetitions <- 1:100
color <-"Blues"
#Generate 100 values for x1, x2, y1, y2, but I don't know how?
xlim <- c(x1, x2)
ylim <- c(y1, y2)

start <- proc.time()
cl <- makeCluster(4) 
results <- parSapply(cl , repetitions , get_mandelbrot_set,xlim,ylim,color) #I don't know how to pass the parameters to the get_mandelbrot_set function
stopCluster(cl)
end <- proc.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Nice images, but as an [interpreted computer language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677021/is-r-an-interpreted-or-compiled-programming-language) R seems to be a terrible choice for generating Mandelbrot sets. It is basically a statistical tool. The major problem with M-set generation is the billions of computations needed. Parallelism is one approach, but before then you need a very fast iteration algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information Weather Vane. Can you provide me with any other example that I can try? The idea is to learn to work with parallel coding in R.

Comment: Some people use OpenMP to parallelise Mandelbrot generation. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638360/parallelize-mandelbrot-with-openmp) is one of several asked here. I suppose it depends on whether the aim is to become proficient in R (using M-set as the vehicle) or to generate M-sets efficiently.

Comment: Ok, in this case it is to learn to work with parallel code in R.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mandelbrot_Creation_Animation_(800x600).gif