# What are the ways to create an executable from R program

Tags: r

I want to know if there is anyway of creating an executable R program to be run in UNIX. I think RInside will do the job but just want to know if there is any other way of doing this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Note that what you can't do is make a single binary executable file in the same way that you compile simple C programs. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452235/does-an-r-compiler-exist

Answer (score 7):

The exact answer depends on your requirements, but you can start by looking at Rscript (see http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html and http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/using-r-as-a-scripting-language-with-rscript.html), as well as littler (http://code.google.com/p/littler/).

Comment: Belated update: The littler repo is now [here on GitHub](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler).