# How to make R-GUI as standalone application or executable platform independent software

Tags: r, rgui

I have made an R-GUI, now i want to make it as an application which can be used as software without running code in 'R' platform, means an executable file which can be run on every windows platform like any other image processing software or any other software like ERDAS or itself R...is it possible to make with in itself R

Comment: I think you misuse the word `software`. If you want to use the functions of R you need to install it, locally or remotely(server machine). I think this is true for any software.

Comment: My apologies for that, i just want to know that the GUI i have made can i use it as a software like we use any image processing software etc.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make an executable in the sense that people no longer need to install R. What you can do is have a look at `Rscript`. This enables you to create R programs, e.g. your GUI, that can be run using a shortcut. Note that this still requires your users to install R, and add the location of the R set of executables (R, Rscript, etc, all in `$R_HOME/bin`) to their `$PATH` environment variable.

See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918553/what-are-the-ways-to-create-an-executable-from-r-program).

Comment: That means user has to install R in any case even if he/she wants to use it as a software ?

Comment: so can i make an application which install R and then run itself and then open the GUI i have made and user can interact with the GUI and do processing with that GUI?

Comment: Installing R on Windows is easy enough (get .exe, run .exe, click OK), so just put that as a requirement in the documentation for your software. Really. No need to complicate your package with an extra installer for R.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for the valuable suggestions @PaulHiemstra and Spacedman

Comment: ...and under MacOS, installing R is also rather straightforward (although you need XCode and a gfortran compiler), and under Linux it is just one command.

Comment: Update: R it's one click away also on Mac Os X now via a normal .dmg installer. No XCode required