# Interfacing R with other non-Java languages / Compiling R to executable

Tags: r, executable

I've developed a .R script that works with a DB, does a bunch of processing and outputs graphs and tables. I can output that data as comma-separated values and pictures, to later import them on my software, that I have no issue.

The problem is how can I distribute my application without having to make a complete install of R on the client. I've seen things like RJava, but my app is on VB6 (yeah...) and I don't see any libraries, or ways to compile to exe. The `compile` package only makes compiled versions of any function you define, like what psyco used to do for Python (before Pypy).

Does anyone have some insight on compiling R to avoid having the user to install an entire additional software?

EDIT: [Does an R compiler exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452235/does-an-r-compiler-exist) This question relates deeply to mine, but I haven't seen how it can be used to make a full script an exe. You can just `compile` a main function and `cat` it to a file? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is "no, that will not work".

There simply is no compiler that allows you to shrink-wrap your app. So your best best may be either

- using the headless [Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve) over the network, or
- using the [R (D)COM server used by RExcel et al](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/)